# SSIS DataFlow from Access to MSSQL

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I have a simple DataFlow with two objects the source which is a mdb file and the destination which is an MSSQL database.

The idea is to migrate the data from one to another.

The problem is that the data is extracted from an Access query, and one column has ~1000 characters, and in SSIS in advanced properties the external column has the default 255 length so when i execute the task it tries to truncate it. To disable the throw error on truncate is not an option, and modifying the Length of the external column cannot be done, it throws and error regarding the metadata.

First of all can anyone explain WHY?

Second of all i need a resolution and i need it fast because it's kinda driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access supports queries which are the equivalent to views in MSSQL. 
The column size is defined not by looking at a few results but by the default column length of the column data type.

I created another table with the desired data types and before the data flow i've put in the package 2 sql scripts: one to delete all the data in the table and one to execute the query against the table, as to treat it as a temporary table.

Then the actual data flow is executed against this pseudo-temporary table.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem occours, because the ssis task "guesses" the length of the column by inspecting the first 100(afaik) rows. So if all rows from 1 to 100 have a length of 10 and the row 101 has the legnth of 11, the task will fail, because the length was "guessed" to 10.

Modifying throws an error, because you have `validateExternalMetadata` set to `true`. To solve this problem, go to `advanced options` of your import task (access) and set the value to `false`. 
This means, the task will accept modified values you entered without checking it.

Comment: the problem with this is that i already tried to make it so the first row will have more thank x characters, and indeed the len is as expected, but when i actually look at the data/try to import the data it throws it in my face... the data will be truncated bla bla bla

Comment: may your data include values you set as delimiter? This would explain your problem.

Comment: I solved the problem. I created a temp table to store the results with a specific length for the given column... and it worked... the data itself had a bunch of space delimited characters. the metadata for a query just gets the default values for the return type of each column. Using a temp table solves this limitation...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to **SSIS Import and Export Wizard** to import the data, from within the BI development environment? That is the easiest way with MsAccess as this not only imports the data but also saves the package. If you get an error during the import ( using the wizard), please post it, as this helps in further investigation. Also, as @stb suggested, try having the first record over 1000 characters.

Comment: this is not an option as this needs to be automated.

Comment: I am wondering if you can try this way first and see if there are any issues? As said above, it also saves it as a package, so this can be used to automate it as well.